# express.js cannot find route at reload after initial load

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I created a small express server to serve my react app. It's a static context react app that only uses API calls to fetch and show data.

When I start my server everything goes well and when I navigate to `localhost:5000` the server automatically redirects to `localhost:5000/login`. However, the server throws an error once the login page is loaded and I trigger a reload. It then gives me `Error: Cannot GET /login`.

Does anyone has an idea what goes wrong? Here is the code of my express server script which I trigger with yarn start (added start script in package.json (`"start": "NODE_ENVIRONMENT=production node server.js"`).

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express(); // create express app

// add middleware
app.use(express.static("dist"));

// start express server on port 5000
app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log("server started on port 5000");
});
```

Comment: The code in the question does not serve anything besides the static resources?!

Comment: @pintxo if you have a folder with html this or images you want to serve this is fine I think. Sure, might not be as effective as just pointing nginx to a folder, but say if you have a workflow with pm2 or similar it can be more than nice to have all the things at one place.

Comment: The problem is likely that there is no history mode fallback. In modern web-applications, the webapp (react) handles the page changes by faking page changes and modifying the url in the addressbar. You fix this by redirecting everything that isn't an asset (or something else) back to to your top index.html. This is why you can click your way to `/login` but not reload while there.

Comment: You could try https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-history-api-fallback. The dev-server does history mode fallbacks automatically. Personally I'd use nginx for this in production.(Sorry for the spam)